# Apache sometimes displays 404 errors on existing files and doesn't log them

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-404

I run a website at an external webhoster (Strato). From time to time, my users (including me) get 404 errors, that

- occur on existing files (the error is gone at the next try)
- don't show the modified Error-Pages I configured in the .htaccess files
- don't show up in Apache's accesslog (provided by my webhoster).

It's just random (estimating 1 out of 500). Does anyone have an idea what this could be? I use PHP 7.2.15.

Code of error site:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /url.php was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: its possible your host has load balancing or proxies set up, this could be causing the issue if a load balanced server has not yet synchronised data.

Comment: I couldn't find any information about that in my webspace at Strato's. But I've also suspected them to misconfigure something. Unfortunately, at support they only told me it's "faulty programming inside of my website" and referred to the logfiles (where the error doesnt appear) :/

Comment: But does that error you suggest also occur when I haven't changed any files the last hours?